# C/C++ program with the same output as /usr/bin/openssl

Tags: c++, c, openssl

My goal is to create a C/C++ program which encrypts/decypts data (to a file) which is compatible with the standard OpenSSL binary utility.  Ideally an administrator would be able to encrypt text using the command `"/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in input.txt -k password -a "`   ...and then a C/C++ program would be capable of decrypting the base64 hash.

Unfortunately, there are very few examples of AES encryption with OpenSSL and it isn't clear what the default parameters are when using the /usr/bin/openssl utility.  The only aes encryption example I found was this one ( http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36 ), but I haven't been able to get it to produce the same output as /usr/bin/openssl.

Any clues?  Should I look at the source for the openssl utility?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to clone openssl? Anyway, yes, use the source.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, there are very few examples of AES encryption with OpenSSL

You should probably study something like OpenSSL's example [*EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption*](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) first. Its easier to digest and has some technical editing performed to ensure its more correct than many bad examples I have seen.

> isn't clear what the default parameters are when using the /usr/bin/openssl

You would find that in `enc.c`. I believe all the subcommands (like `enc`, `dec`, `s_client`, and `s_server`) have an accompanying source file. You can find it in the `apps` folder: `openssl-1.0.1e\apps\enc.c`. If you want to see how the password is mashed, follow `EVP_read_pw_string`.

```
int MAIN(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static const char magic[]="Salted__";
    char mbuf[sizeof magic-1];
    char *strbuf=NULL;
    unsigned char *buff=NULL,*bufsize=NULL;
    int bsize=BSIZE,verbose=0;
    int ret=1,inl;
    int nopad = 0;
    unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH],iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
    char *str=NULL, *passarg = NULL, *pass = NULL;
    char *hkey=NULL,*hiv=NULL,*hsalt = NULL;
    char *md=NULL;
    int enc=1,printkey=0,i,base64=0;
#ifdef ZLIB
    int do_zlib=0;
    BIO *bzl = NULL;
#endif
    int debug=0,olb64=0,nosalt=0;
    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher=NULL,*c;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    char *inf=NULL,*outf=NULL;
    BIO *in=NULL,*out=NULL,*b64=NULL,*benc=NULL,*rbio=NULL,*wbio=NULL;
#define PROG_NAME_SIZE  39
    char pname[PROG_NAME_SIZE+1];
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
    char *engine = NULL;
#endif
    const EVP_MD *dgst=NULL;
    int non_fips_allow = 0;

    apps_startup();

    if (bio_err == NULL)
        if ((bio_err=BIO_new(BIO_s_file())) != NULL)
            BIO_set_fp(bio_err,stderr,BIO_NOCLOSE|BIO_FP_TEXT);

    if (!load_config(bio_err, NULL))
        goto end;

    /* first check the program name */
    program_name(argv[0],pname,sizeof pname);
    if (strcmp(pname,"base64") == 0)
        base64=1;
#ifdef ZLIB
    if (strcmp(pname,"zlib") == 0)
        do_zlib=1;
#endif

    cipher=EVP_get_cipherbyname(pname);
#ifdef ZLIB
    if (!do_zlib && !base64 && (cipher == NULL)
        && (strcmp(pname,"enc") != 0))
#else
        if (!base64 && (cipher == NULL) && (strcmp(pname,"enc") != 0))
#endif
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%s is an unknown cipher\n",pname);
            goto bad;
        }

    argc--;
    argv++;
    while (argc >= 1)
    {
        if  (strcmp(*argv,"-e") == 0)
            enc=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-in") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            inf= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-out") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            outf= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-pass") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            passarg= *(++argv);
        }
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-engine") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            engine= *(++argv);
        }
#endif
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-d") == 0)
            enc=0;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-p") == 0)
            printkey=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-v") == 0)
            verbose=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-nopad") == 0)
            nopad=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-salt") == 0)
            nosalt=0;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-nosalt") == 0)
            nosalt=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-debug") == 0)
            debug=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-P") == 0)
            printkey=2;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-A") == 0)
            olb64=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-a") == 0)
            base64=1;
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-base64") == 0)
            base64=1;
#ifdef ZLIB
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-z") == 0)
            do_zlib=1;
#endif
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-bufsize") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            bufsize=(unsigned char *)*(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-k") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            str= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-kfile") == 0)
        {
            static char buf[128];
            FILE *infile;
            char *file;

            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            file= *(++argv);
            infile=fopen(file,"r");
            if (infile == NULL)
            {
                BIO_printf(bio_err,"unable to read key from '%s'\n",
                           file);
                goto bad;
            }
            buf[0]='\0';
            if (!fgets(buf,sizeof buf,infile))
            {
                BIO_printf(bio_err,"unable to read key from '%s'\n",
                           file);
                goto bad;
            }
            fclose(infile);
            i=strlen(buf);
            if ((i > 0) &&
                ((buf[i-1] == '\n') || (buf[i-1] == '\r')))
                buf[--i]='\0';
            if ((i > 0) &&
                ((buf[i-1] == '\n') || (buf[i-1] == '\r')))
                buf[--i]='\0';
            if (i < 1)
            {
                BIO_printf(bio_err,"zero length password\n");
                goto bad;
            }
            str=buf;
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-K") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            hkey= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-S") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            hsalt= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-iv") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            hiv= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-md") == 0)
        {
            if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
            md= *(++argv);
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-non-fips-allow") == 0)
            non_fips_allow = 1;
        else if ((argv[0][0] == '-') &&
                 ((c=EVP_get_cipherbyname(&(argv[0][1]))) != NULL))
        {
            cipher=c;
        }
        else if (strcmp(*argv,"-none") == 0)
            cipher=NULL;
        else
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"unknown option '%s'\n",*argv);
        bad:
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"options are\n");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s input file\n","-in <file>");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s output file\n","-out <file>");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s pass phrase source\n","-pass <arg>");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s encrypt\n","-e");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s decrypt\n","-d");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s base64 encode/decode, depending on encryption flag\n","-a/-base64");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s passphrase is the next argument\n","-k");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s passphrase is the first line of the file argument\n","-kfile");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s the next argument is the md to use to create a key\n","-md");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s   from a passphrase.  One of md2, md5, sha or sha1\n","");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s salt in hex is the next argument\n","-S");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s key/iv in hex is the next argument\n","-K/-iv");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s print the iv/key (then exit if -P)\n","-[pP]");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s buffer size\n","-bufsize <n>");
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s disable standard block padding\n","-nopad");
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"%-14s use engine e, possibly a hardware device.\n","-engine e");
#endif

            BIO_printf(bio_err,"Cipher Types\n");
            OBJ_NAME_do_all_sorted(OBJ_NAME_TYPE_CIPHER_METH,
                                   show_ciphers,
                                   bio_err);
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"\n");

            goto end;
        }
        argc--;
        argv++;
    }

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
    setup_engine(bio_err, engine, 0);
#endif

    if (md && (dgst=EVP_get_digestbyname(md)) == NULL)
    {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"%s is an unsupported message digest type\n",md);
        goto end;
    }

    if (dgst == NULL)
    {
        dgst = EVP_md5();
    }

    if (bufsize != NULL)
    {
        unsigned long n;

        for (n=0; *bufsize; bufsize++)
        {
            i= *bufsize;
            if ((i <= '9') && (i >= '0'))
                n=n*10+i-'0';
            else if (i == 'k')
            {
                n*=1024;
                bufsize++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (*bufsize != '\0')
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"invalid 'bufsize' specified.\n");
            goto end;
        }

        /* It must be large enough for a base64 encoded line */
        if (base64 && n < 80) n=80;

        bsize=(int)n;
        if (verbose) BIO_printf(bio_err,"bufsize=%d\n",bsize);
    }

    strbuf=OPENSSL_malloc(SIZE);
    buff=(unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_ENCODE_LENGTH(bsize));
    if ((buff == NULL) || (strbuf == NULL))
    {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"OPENSSL_malloc failure %ld\n",(long)EVP_ENCODE_LENGTH(bsize));
        goto end;
    }

    in=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    out=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    if ((in == NULL) || (out == NULL))
    {
        ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
        goto end;
    }
    if (debug)
    {
        BIO_set_callback(in,BIO_debug_callback);
        BIO_set_callback(out,BIO_debug_callback);
        BIO_set_callback_arg(in,(char *)bio_err);
        BIO_set_callback_arg(out,(char *)bio_err);
    }

    if (inf == NULL)
    {
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SETVBUF_IONBF
        if (bufsize != NULL)
            setvbuf(stdin, (char *)NULL, _IONBF, 0);
#endif /* ndef OPENSSL_NO_SETVBUF_IONBF */
        BIO_set_fp(in,stdin,BIO_NOCLOSE);
    }
    else
    {
        if (BIO_read_filename(in,inf) <= 0)
        {
            perror(inf);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    if(!str && passarg) {
        if(!app_passwd(bio_err, passarg, NULL, &pass, NULL)) {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error getting password\n");
            goto end;
        }
        str = pass;
    }

    if ((str == NULL) && (cipher != NULL) && (hkey == NULL))
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            char buf[200];

            BIO_snprintf(buf,sizeof buf,"enter %s %s password:",
                         OBJ_nid2ln(EVP_CIPHER_nid(cipher)),
                         (enc)?"encryption":"decryption");
            strbuf[0]='\0';
            i=EVP_read_pw_string((char *)strbuf,SIZE,buf,enc);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (strbuf[0] == '\0')
                {
                    ret=1;
                    goto end;
                }
                str=strbuf;
                break;
            }
            if (i < 0)
            {
                BIO_printf(bio_err,"bad password read\n");
                goto end;
            }
        }
    }


    if (outf == NULL)
    {
        BIO_set_fp(out,stdout,BIO_NOCLOSE);
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SETVBUF_IONBF
        if (bufsize != NULL)
            setvbuf(stdout, (char *)NULL, _IONBF, 0);
#endif /* ndef OPENSSL_NO_SETVBUF_IONBF */
#ifdef OPENSSL_SYS_VMS
        {
            BIO *tmpbio = BIO_new(BIO_f_linebuffer());
            out = BIO_push(tmpbio, out);
        }
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        if (BIO_write_filename(out,outf) <= 0)
        {
            perror(outf);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    rbio=in;
    wbio=out;

#ifdef ZLIB

    if (do_zlib)
    {
        if ((bzl=BIO_new(BIO_f_zlib())) == NULL)
            goto end;
        if (enc)
            wbio=BIO_push(bzl,wbio);
        else
            rbio=BIO_push(bzl,rbio);
    }
#endif

    if (base64)
    {
        if ((b64=BIO_new(BIO_f_base64())) == NULL)
            goto end;
        if (debug)
        {
            BIO_set_callback(b64,BIO_debug_callback);
            BIO_set_callback_arg(b64,(char *)bio_err);
        }
        if (olb64)
            BIO_set_flags(b64,BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
        if (enc)
            wbio=BIO_push(b64,wbio);
        else
            rbio=BIO_push(b64,rbio);
    }

    if (cipher != NULL)
    {
        /* Note that str is NULL if a key was passed on the command
         * line, so we get no salt in that case. Is this a bug?
         */
        if (str != NULL)
        {
            /* Salt handling: if encrypting generate a salt and
             * write to output BIO. If decrypting read salt from
             * input BIO.
             */
            unsigned char *sptr;
            if(nosalt) sptr = NULL;
            else {
                if(enc) {
                    if(hsalt) {
                        if(!set_hex(hsalt,salt,sizeof salt)) {
                            BIO_printf(bio_err,
                                       "invalid hex salt value\n");
                            goto end;
                        }
                    } else if (RAND_pseudo_bytes(salt, sizeof salt) < 0)
                        goto end;
                    /* If -P option then don't bother writing */
                    if((printkey != 2)
                       && (BIO_write(wbio,magic,
                                     sizeof magic-1) != sizeof magic-1
                           || BIO_write(wbio,
                                        (char *)salt,
                                        sizeof salt) != sizeof salt)) {
                               BIO_printf(bio_err,"error writing output file\n");
                               goto end;
                           }
                } else if(BIO_read(rbio,mbuf,sizeof mbuf) != sizeof mbuf
                          || BIO_read(rbio,
                                      (unsigned char *)salt,
                                      sizeof salt) != sizeof salt) {
                              BIO_printf(bio_err,"error reading input file\n");
                              goto end;
                          } else if(memcmp(mbuf,magic,sizeof magic-1)) {
                              BIO_printf(bio_err,"bad magic number\n");
                              goto end;
                          }

                sptr = salt;
            }

            EVP_BytesToKey(cipher,dgst,sptr,
                           (unsigned char *)str,
                           strlen(str),1,key,iv);
            /* zero the complete buffer or the string
             * passed from the command line
             * bug picked up by
             * Larry J. Hughes Jr. <hughes@indiana.edu> */
            if (str == strbuf)
                OPENSSL_cleanse(str,SIZE);
            else
                OPENSSL_cleanse(str,strlen(str));
        }
        if ((hiv != NULL) && !set_hex(hiv,iv,sizeof iv))
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"invalid hex iv value\n");
            goto end;
        }
        if ((hiv == NULL) && (str == NULL)
            && EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher) != 0)
        {
            /* No IV was explicitly set and no IV was generated
             * during EVP_BytesToKey. Hence the IV is undefined,
             * making correct decryption impossible. */
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "iv undefined\n");
            goto end;
        }
        if ((hkey != NULL) && !set_hex(hkey,key,sizeof key))
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"invalid hex key value\n");
            goto end;
        }

        if ((benc=BIO_new(BIO_f_cipher())) == NULL)
            goto end;

        /* Since we may be changing parameters work on the encryption
         * context rather than calling BIO_set_cipher().
         */

        BIO_get_cipher_ctx(benc, &ctx);

        if (non_fips_allow)
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_flags(ctx,
                                     EVP_CIPH_FLAG_NON_FIPS_ALLOW);

        if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, enc))
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error setting cipher %s\n",
                       EVP_CIPHER_name(cipher));
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            goto end;
        }

        if (nopad)
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);

        if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, enc))
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error setting cipher %s\n",
                       EVP_CIPHER_name(cipher));
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            goto end;
        }

        if (debug)
        {
            BIO_set_callback(benc,BIO_debug_callback);
            BIO_set_callback_arg(benc,(char *)bio_err);
        }

        if (printkey)
        {
            if (!nosalt)
            {
                printf("salt=");
                for (i=0; i<(int)sizeof(salt); i++)
                    printf("%02X",salt[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
            if (cipher->key_len > 0)
            {
                printf("key=");
                for (i=0; i<cipher->key_len; i++)
                    printf("%02X",key[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
            if (cipher->iv_len > 0)
            {
                printf("iv =");
                for (i=0; i<cipher->iv_len; i++)
                    printf("%02X",iv[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
            if (printkey == 2)
            {
                ret=0;
                goto end;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Only encrypt/decrypt as we write the file */
    if (benc != NULL)
        wbio=BIO_push(benc,wbio);

    for (;;)
    {
        inl=BIO_read(rbio,(char *)buff,bsize);
        if (inl <= 0) break;
        if (BIO_write(wbio,(char *)buff,inl) != inl)
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err,"error writing output file\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    if (!BIO_flush(wbio))
    {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"bad decrypt\n");
        goto end;
    }

    ret=0;
    if (verbose)
    {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"bytes read   :%8ld\n",BIO_number_read(in));
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"bytes written:%8ld\n",BIO_number_written(out));
    }
end:
    ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
    if (strbuf != NULL) OPENSSL_free(strbuf);
    if (buff != NULL) OPENSSL_free(buff);
    if (in != NULL) BIO_free(in);
    if (out != NULL) BIO_free_all(out);
    if (benc != NULL) BIO_free(benc);
    if (b64 != NULL) BIO_free(b64);
#ifdef ZLIB
    if (bzl != NULL) BIO_free(bzl);
#endif
    if(pass) OPENSSL_free(pass);
    apps_shutdown();
    OPENSSL_EXIT(ret);
}
```